# How to reshape 3d numpy array into 2d array, keeping the z axis dimension

Tags: python, dask

[image]
I created an array from a stack of images. 
The images are 10980 * 10980 in size. 
I used dask to read the images and stack them, using the lazy array approach. 
They are 68 in total.
I used the following code:

```
import dask
import dask.array as da
import glob
import time
import os

filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for root, subdir, filenames in os.walk("L2A")
            for filename in filenames if filename.endswith("B04_10m.tif")]

print(len(filenames))

import imageio 
sample = imageio.imread(filenames[0])
sample.shape

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import skimage.io 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
skimage.io.imshow(sample[:,:])

lazy_arrays = [dask.delayed(imageio.imread)(fn) for fn in filenames]

lazy_arrays = [da.from_delayed(x, shape=sample.shape, dtype=sample.dtype)
              for x in lazy_arrays]

array = da.stack(lazy_arrays, axis=0)
array
```

The array's shape is:
Shape   (68, 10980, 10980) 
However what I would like to have is a 2d Array that keeps the along axis z dimension (68), which will be the in the new 2d array, and that the 10980 and 10980 dimension (rows and columns in 3D array), would the columns in the new 2d array. 
At the end the shape I am looking for is (68, 120560400). Does anyone know how to do that? The goal is to calculate the mean of the stack, because doing it using a nested for loop to iterate over the columns and rows of the 3d dimension will very long, using the following function.

```
    x = array.shape[1]
    y = array.shape[2]
    values = np.empty((x,y), type(array[0][0][0]))
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            values[i][j] = ((np.mean(array[:,i,j])))
```

Comment: I think you just need to flatten it. I guess you could use `numpy.reshape`

Comment: array.reshape((68,10980*10980)) Unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Thanks! It was easier than I thought!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a "bunch of multidimensional things" as a single numpy array, such as your set of images, then **it is better to use the first dimension to index the individual things**.

This makes everything simpler. Selecting the n-th image is just `array[n-1]` and you can easily flatten all images in the array while keeping the images separated as you want with just `array.reshape((array.shape[0], -1))`.

**Note**: we can use `-1` in one of the dimensions in order to ask numpy to compute the appropriated size for us, which in your case it will compute as `10980*10980`.